# Making jButtons mutually exclusive in java swing

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Please guys how do I make a jButton mouseClicked action mutually exclusive for each button in a set of buttons generated from a loop.. I've tried buttonGroup that's used for radio button but it isn't working..

Comment: Not sure what you mean - please try and explain more clearly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Try making a group of radio buttons to do what you want, then make them invisible.  Create a group of jButtons, each linked to one of the invisible radio buttons.  Pass the click/select/unselect actions both ways so the jButtons react the same as the radio button they are linked to.

Comment: post the code you wrote...

Comment: @BarrySW19, Lemme put it this way.. If I click a button, d color changes due to my mouse clicked action and when I click another button, the color also changes meaning I have two buttons with changed color instead of One..

Comment: @rossum please how do I assign d jbutton to the jradiobutton corresponding to it?

Comment: Link the actions.  Clicking the jButton triggers selecting the linked radio button.  That will automatically unselect other radio buttons, and link that unselecting action to unselecting the other linked jButton.  Link the button actions so actions on one of the pair are mirrored in the other member of the pair.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use `JToggleButton` and `ButtonGroup`, here is simple example:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;


public class MutuallyExclusiveJToggleButtons extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MutuallyExclusiveJToggleButtons().setVisible(true);
    }

    public MutuallyExclusiveJToggleButtons () {
        setSize(300,300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JToggleButton button1 = new JToggleButton("1");
        JToggleButton button2 = new JToggleButton("2");
        JToggleButton button3 = new JToggleButton("3");
        JToggleButton button4 = new JToggleButton("4");

        ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();

        bg.add(button1);
        bg.add(button2);
        bg.add(button3);
        bg.add(button4);

        getContentPane().add(button1);
        getContentPane().add(button2);
        getContentPane().add(button3);
        getContentPane().add(button4);

    }

}
```

The result will look like this: Four buttons, only one from them can be toggled at the moment:

[image]